# Klout API not working

Tags: klout

i try to follow this: [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/jstwitter.html) --use klout api to calculate my follower's klout score.(at the bottom of the link page )here is the instruction:

```
First, hop into Terminal and run this line:

1. gem install klout

Next, open irb so you can experiment with the Klout API. Run the following lines:
API_KEY="your-api-key"
k = Klout::API.new(API_KEY)
k.klout("jack")["users"][0]["kscore"]
=> 74.61
```

i did exactly the same, but return "nameError:uninitialized constant Klout"

Comment: You really need to make this question clearer if you expect anyone to be able to help. And code does not belong in a question title.

Answer (score 1):

It's also bad form to post API keys publicly. They are licensed to you and you alone.

That said, it looks like either the gem didn't install properly, or you need to require Klout first.

Comment: oh,it's a tutorial from jumpstarlap, i think it's a public API key?

Comment: i install the gem ,and  require Klout , maybe problem with the key?

Comment: Very likely! You'll need to register for a key of your own at http://developer.klout.com. We also have a number of community-developed wrappers (including a newer ruby Klout wrapper) available in the documentation.